# ios Any idea how to create a field like the "To:" sms or email field?

Tags: ios, email, sms, field, addition

Does anyone know how to create a field like the "To:" sms or email field?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a custom Cell that extends UITableDataCell... I don't have the code in front of me... but, a quick google search should be able to help you

Comment: I know how to implement a tableview. I was refering about the blue/green bubble around the text

Comment: Ahh... I would edit your question... good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/titokenfield
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jstokenfield
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/copeoplepickerviewcontroller

I haven't tried them myself yet, but the ratings look good.